# How to build older modernizr version from git clone?

Tags: git, modernizr

I cloned the modernizr repo from git today to maintain the resources I require at a central place. After downloading it I ran `grunt build` and well received the `modernizr-build.js` file in the `dist` directory. However, I encounter some issues with this file as it appears to be an alpha release as claimed I the file header. From the modernizr website I know the latest stable release is 2.8.3. So I checked the git history for this extension but cannot find a line containing this number. The last line containing a version number close to the latest stable contains version 2.6.3.
Can you tell me, how to find out the hash for version 2.8.3 to check that out and build from it?

Please don't ask me why I don't go for the zip file from the modernizr website. The answer is: I am learning to use git and building from source. I am aware of the custom download builder at http://modernizr.com but would like to learn how to use git and grunt and get an answer to my question, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modernizr on github has been at 3.0-alpha status for a *very* long time, all of the releases since 2.6 onward have been from the `backport-fixes` branch. That being said, before 3.0, there was one central file, with a number of "community" detects that could be added or removed. The building process either added content to this file, or stripped out sections from it. It is before my time on the project, so I am not 100%, but I do not believe there is a way to build the old version like you would in the web builder, outside of the web builder.

Comment: Sad to hear. I'm yet waiting see if there'll be more replies before i accept your answer.

Comment: I am the lead maintainer of modernizr. I don't know who would have more information.

Comment: Ok. Then, can you as the lead maintainer tell me whether it is planned to structure the repo for such cases or will going back to a previous version be possible from version 3 onwards only in the future?

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question - are you saying are we planning on allowing for you to build old versions? No.

Comment: It would be useful to be able to add features to an older version if for some reason you did not want to upgrade but wanted to add a new test